# How can I define variables as a comparator group including all variables except X?

Tags: r, grouping, subset, contingency

I have a database with a column that has the different country of occurrence and another column with the type of event happened (3000+ entries) and is structured as exampled below:

```
#>   country           event
#> 1     USA           Abdominal discomfort
#> 2     USA           Abdominal discomfort
#> 3  Canada           Vomiting
#> 4      UK           Alopecia
#> 5  Hungary          Agitation     
#> 6  France           Abscess
```

So, as you can imagine I have thousands of different variables!

I want to compute the values for a contingency table like this:

|  | X event | Not X event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S | a | b |
| C | c | d |

S = subset of interest (for example, United States)
C = comparator (all other countries in the database)

My main question is how can I create a code that allows me to **create a new variable defining the group of all countries in the database except US** or **a new variable defining the group of all events that are not the "X event"**, so I can get to the values of b and d?

**The final goal of this study is to see if there is a determined event that happens more frequently in a country than in the others**

Thanks and sorry if I am not expressing myself in the most correct way, I am completely new to RStudio and coding.

Comment: It would be easier, if you include an input and an expected output in your question.

Comment: @MartinGal hope the information I added helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your data is in this format:

```r
df <- data.frame(country = c('USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'UK', 'UK', 'France',
                             'Hungary', 'Hungary', 'France', 'Canada'),
                 event = c('Vomiting', 'Agitation', 'Headache', 'Headache',
                           'Abdominal pain', 'Vomiting', 'Agitation', 
                           'Abdominal pain', 'Anaphylaxis', 'Vomiting'))
df
#>    country          event
#> 1      USA       Vomiting
#> 2      USA      Agitation
#> 3   Canada       Headache
#> 4       UK       Headache
#> 5       UK Abdominal pain
#> 6   France       Vomiting
#> 7  Hungary      Agitation
#> 8  Hungary Abdominal pain
#> 9   France    Anaphylaxis
#> 10  Canada       Vomiting
```

That being the case, you would require one table for each condition in each country, which may result in dozens or hundreds of different tables to process (for example, there would be 25 tables even for this little toy example).

To help summarize your data, you could directly get the odds ratio and p value for each condition in each country by creating each table inside an `lapply` call and doing a Fisher test to extract the statistics out of it. Then you can turn the whole thing into a data frame:

```r
`row.names<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(sort(unique(df$event)), function(x) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(sort(unique(df$country)), function(y) {
  tab <- table(df$country == y, df$event == x)
  ft <- fisher.test(tab)
  data.frame(country = y, condition = x, event = tab[2, 2], no_event = tab[2, 1],
             ROW_event = tab[1, 2], ROW_no_event = tab[1, 1],
             odds_ratio = ft$estimate,
             p_value = ft$p.value)
  }))
})), NULL)
#>    country      condition event no_event ROW_event ROW_no_event odds_ratio
#> 1   Canada Abdominal pain     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 2   France Abdominal pain     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 3  Hungary Abdominal pain     1        1         1            7   5.291552
#> 4       UK Abdominal pain     1        1         1            7   5.291552
#> 5      USA Abdominal pain     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 6   Canada      Agitation     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 7   France      Agitation     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 8  Hungary      Agitation     1        1         1            7   5.291552
#> 9       UK      Agitation     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 10     USA      Agitation     1        1         1            7   5.291552
#> 11  Canada    Anaphylaxis     0        2         1            7   0.000000
#> 12  France    Anaphylaxis     1        1         0            8        Inf
#> 13 Hungary    Anaphylaxis     0        2         1            7   0.000000
#> 14      UK    Anaphylaxis     0        2         1            7   0.000000
#> 15     USA    Anaphylaxis     0        2         1            7   0.000000
#> 16  Canada       Headache     1        1         1            7   5.291552
#> 17  France       Headache     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 18 Hungary       Headache     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 19      UK       Headache     1        1         1            7   5.291552
#> 20     USA       Headache     0        2         2            6   0.000000
#> 21  Canada       Vomiting     1        1         2            6   2.645752
#> 22  France       Vomiting     1        1         2            6   2.645752
#> 23 Hungary       Vomiting     0        2         3            5   0.000000
#> 24      UK       Vomiting     0        2         3            5   0.000000
#> 25     USA       Vomiting     1        1         2            6   2.645752
#>      p_value
#> 1  1.0000000
#> 2  1.0000000
#> 3  0.3777778
#> 4  0.3777778
#> 5  1.0000000
#> 6  1.0000000
#> 7  1.0000000
#> 8  0.3777778
#> 9  1.0000000
#> 10 0.3777778
#> 11 1.0000000
#> 12 0.2000000
#> 13 1.0000000
#> 14 1.0000000
#> 15 1.0000000
#> 16 0.3777778
#> 17 1.0000000
#> 18 1.0000000
#> 19 0.3777778
#> 20 1.0000000
#> 21 1.0000000
#> 22 1.0000000
#> 23 1.0000000
#> 24 1.0000000
#> 25 1.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Dear Allan,

My data has 3000+ entries and is structured as exampled below:

#>   country           event
#> 1     USA           Abdominal discomfort
#> 2     USA           Abdominal discomfort
#> 3  Canada         Vomiting
#> 4      UK            Alopecia
#> 5  Hungary       Agitation     
#> 6  France          Abscess

So, as you can imagine I have thousands of different variables! 

Is there an easier and fastest way of grouping with the objectives aforementioned? Or do I have to manually insert all of the different categories in the code you mentioned?

Comment: @hmcmar but what output are you looking for? Do you want a table for each event type?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for. The final goal of this study is to see if there is a determined event that happens more frequently in a country than in the others. Thank you!

Comment: @hmcmar see my update - hopefully that helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will try to do it as you said. 
Have a nice day!

Comment: I have adapted the code you sent me to my database and variables, however when I run the code there's no error message in the console but there's also no action from R. Why does this happen? Can you help me please?

Comment: @hmcmar I would need to see your data to help you further. Can you post a link to a csv copy of your data?